# git-prompt + TMOUT

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I recently found bash `TMOUT`, which for me works fine for normal sessions, but in combination with git-prompt the timeout does not seem to be respected -- the shell stays open indefinitely.

I tried searching around, but nothing really matches my description, i tried *"TMOUT" AND "PROMPT_COMMAND"* but there no results matching my problem.

Any hints where I could look?

```
cschulz@DESKTOP-FL37PIH:/tmp/tmp.dLEDcMLmDK
$2 ls -la
total 20
drwx------  3 cschulz cschulz  4096 Oct 27 14:40 .
drwxrwxrwt 95 root    root    12288 Oct 27 14:40 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 cschulz cschulz  4096 Oct 27 14:40 git

cschulz@DESKTOP-FL37PIH:/tmp/tmp.dLEDcMLmDK
$2 bash; echo "Bash quit"

cschulz@DESKTOP-FL37PIH:/tmp/tmp.dLEDcMLmDK
$3 TMOUT=1

cschulz@DESKTOP-FL37PIH:/tmp/tmp.dLEDcMLmDK
timed out waiting for input: auto-logout
Bash quit

cschulz@DESKTOP-FL37PIH:/tmp/tmp.dLEDcMLmDK
$2
```

```
cschulz@DESKTOP-FL37PIH:/tmp/tmp.dLEDcMLmDK/git
[master # ]$2 ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 cschulz cschulz 4096 Oct 27 14:40 .
drwx------ 3 cschulz cschulz 4096 Oct 27 14:40 ..
drwxrwxr-x 7 cschulz cschulz 4096 Oct 27 14:40 .git

cschulz@DESKTOP-FL37PIH:/tmp/tmp.dLEDcMLmDK/git
[master # ]$2 bash; echo "Bash quit"

cschulz@DESKTOP-FL37PIH:/tmp/tmp.dLEDcMLmDK/git
[master # ]$3 TMOUT=1

cschulz@DESKTOP-FL37PIH:/tmp/tmp.dLEDcMLmDK/git
[master # ]$3 date
Thu 27 Oct 14:43:21 CEST 2022

cschulz@DESKTOP-FL37PIH:/tmp/tmp.dLEDcMLmDK/git
[master # ]$3 date
Thu 27 Oct 14:43:24 CEST 2022

cschulz@DESKTOP-FL37PIH:/tmp/tmp.dLEDcMLmDK/git
[master # ]$3
```

```
# my PROMPT_COMMAND

cschulz@DESKTOP-FL37PIH:~
$2 echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
__git_ps1 "\n\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[01;00m\]@\[\033[01;32m\]\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\n\[\033[00m\]" "\\\$$([ $SHLVL -gt 1 ] && echo $SHLVL) " "[%s $(get_sha)]"

cschulz@DESKTOP-FL37PIH:~
$2 type get_sha
get_sha is a function
get_sha ()
{
    git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null
}

# _git_ps1 comes from /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt, from git 1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following snippet causes the `TMOUT` to be ignored, i commented it out and now my `TMOUT` works as expected inside git repositories as well. :)

```bash
        #while read -r key value; do
        #       case "$key" in
        #       bash.showupstream)
        #               GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="$value"
        #               if [[ -z "${GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM}" ]]; then
        #                       p=""
        #                       return
        #               fi
        #               ;;
        #       svn-remote.*.url)
        #               svn_remote[$((${#svn_remote[@]} + 1))]="$value"
        #               svn_url_pattern="$svn_url_pattern\\|$value"
        #               upstream=svn+git # default upstream is SVN if available, else git
        #               ;;
        #       esac
        #done <<< "$output"
```